# CreateJS/AnimateCC Iterate through children of a library MovieClip

Tags: flash, createjs, animate-cc

I've created a MovieClip Symbol in AnimateCC which is made up of other MovieClip Symbols. I want to iterate through the children of the parent MovieClip at runtime to amend some of the child symbols properties.
I thought it would be easy using something like :-

```
for (var i= 0; i < this.MyThing.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    var child = this.MyThing.getChildAt(i);
    // then amend child properties
}
```

But this doesn't work. When I look in the js file it seems that the children are added as properties of the instance e.g.

```
this.T1 = new lib.Thing1();
```

rather than how you'd add children normally like:-

```
var PA = new lib.Thing1();
this.ParentThing.addChild(PA);
```

So is there a way of getting at the child objects dynamically at run time by iterating through children rather than hardcoding the names of the child MovieClips?

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug introduced to Animate when Adobe changed all single-frame timelines from Containers to MovieClips, and children are not immediately available. Children of MovieClips are added to the timeline via Tween timelines. There *should* be an `addChild` call in the constructor, but there is not.

You can get around this by calling `gotoAndStop(0)` and then iterating the children.

```
this.gotoAndStop(0);
console.log(this.children);
```

Hope that solves your issue. Hopefully this gets solved in the next Adobe Animate release.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for that.